# Set an optimization using LMFIT and Parameters class with condition to be checked

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

How to use ExpressionModel in LMFIT to fit a conditional model that can be represented as:

```
from lmfit.models import ExpressionModel
# read(xdata and ydata) here
if xdata < some_parameter_value:
    model = ExpressionModel('expression1')
else:
    model = ExpressionModel('expression2')
```

How to write this conditional model as one model (global_model) and pass it to the fit method

```
results = global_model.fit(y, x = x, parameters_dictionary)
```

some_parameter_value: is a member of parameters_dictionary which is created using Parameters class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lmfit Models are defined independent of the data and cannot be used for "part of the data".

Perhaps you can rewrite the expression for the model as:

```
 expr1 if x < x0 else expr2
```

Otherwise, I think you'll have to write a custom Model that tests the condition and does a different calculation based on that condition.